# 403 ERROR when i'm trying to upload file on server Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload

I've got a 403 ERROR when i'm trying to upload file in server! What the problem? Help me pls! Can't uderstand what a trouble. Thanx
This is my Controller

```
  @Controller
@SessionAttributes("username")
public class UserPageController {

    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file)
    {
String name="";
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

                // Creating the directory to store file
                String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
                File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
                if (!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();

                // Create the file on server
                File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                        + File.separator + name);
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();


                return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name
                    + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String postAvatar(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
    {
        uploadFile(file);
        return"redirect:/user";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUserInfo(Model model, Principal principal) {
        String username=principal.getName();
        model.addAttribute("users", new Users());
        model.addAttribute("userInfo", this.usersService.userInfo(username));
        return "user";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/user/search/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAnotherUserInfo(@ModelAttribute("message") Message message, @PathVariable(value="username") String username, Model model, Principal principal) {
        if(username.equals(principal.getName()))
        {
            model.addAttribute("users", new Users());
            model.addAttribute("userInfo", this.usersService.userInfo(username));
            return "redirect:/user";
        }
        else{
        model.addAttribute("users", new Users());
        model.addAttribute("userInfo", this.usersService.userInfo(username));
        return "anotherUser";
        }
    }
```

And this is my .jsp page. My form is in the bottom of page

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
    prefix="security"%>
<%@page language="java" session="true"%>

<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Профиль | Violence and Hate</title>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootswatch.less.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/variables.less.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Violence and Hate</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

   <li><a href="/app/user">Профиль</a></li>
<li><a href="/app/user/messages">Сообщения</a></li>
<li><a href="/app/user/search">Поиск оппонента</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Информация<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/app/user/rules">Правила</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="/app/user/feedback">Написать администрации</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Администрирование<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/app/admin">Админка/Список пользователей</a></li>
            <li><a href="/app/admin/feedbacklist">Отзывы/Вопросы/Предложения</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        </security:authorize>
      </ul>

    <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="j_spring_security_logout" />
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Выйти</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" />
                    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="<c:url value="/resources/logo/logo.png"/>" />

<br>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
  <!-- Default panel contents -->
  <div class="panel-heading text-center">Личная информация</div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                <tr>
                <th>Ник</th>
                <th>Имя</th>
                <th>Фамилия</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Пол</th>
                <th>Вес(кг)</th>
                <th>Рост(см)</th>
                <th>Спортивные умения</th>
                <th>Место</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <c:forEach items="${userInfo}" var="users">
                <td>${users.username}</td>
                <td>${users.name}</td>

                <td>${users.surname}</td>

                <td>${users.email}</td>

                <td>${users.gender}</td>


                <td>${users.weight}</td>

                <td>${users.height}</td>

                <td>${users.sport}</td>

                <td>${users.place}</td>
                    </c:forEach>
    </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
 <form method="POST" action="user" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br />  
        <input type="submit" value="Аплоад"> Press here to upload the file!
    </form>

    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/Jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"/>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"/>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd


     "
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">


    <context:component-scan base-package="
    com.vandh.app " />


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>

                    <!-- Mail Sending properties -->
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
        <property name="username" value="violandhate@gmail.com" />
        <property name="password" value="violenceandhate" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

        <bean id="multipartResolver"
   class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000"/>
</bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>     
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">



        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I suspect this is a CSRF issue.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064000/uploading-file-returns-403-error-spring-mvc

Comment: Your file save code looks a little dangerous. `name` used to create the filename seems to be a set to `""`, which is appended to a catalina path. I guess this will be later changed to use a user supplied value, making it far too easy to hack your system. In addition, you're making your code Tomcat specific. Use `File.createTempFile()` instead

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack what i need to do? change file saving path?

Comment: Use `File.createTempFile()` to create a random filename in a system temporary directory. Otherwise, it's too easy for a user to create a file called `/etc/passwd`

Comment: @dseibert, thanx! it helped me!