# http status 403 forbidden when uploading files

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am using Spring boot MultipartFile to allow users to upload their files and I want to save the uploaded files in the project directory or on my disk "C:\upload" (or wherever it works locally). When I submit any file, I get the 403 error forbidden. (spring-boot-starter-security is used for the embedded login).

Here is a screenshot of the error printed in the browser: [403 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcf5l.png)

In the console I get the following error:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

This is my project Structure: [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYvlX.png)

This is my uploadController:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@Controller
public class UploadController {

//Save the uploaded file to this folder
private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "./src/main/resources/uploaded";

@GetMapping("/test")
public String index() {
return "upload";
}

@PostMapping("/upload") 
public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                           RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

if (file.isEmpty()) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Please select a file to upload");
    return "redirect:uploadStatus";
}

try {

    // Get the file and save it somewhere
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
    Files.write(path, bytes);

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "You successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return "redirect:/uploadStatus";
}

@GetMapping("/uploadStatus")
public String uploadStatus() {
return "uploadStatus";
}

}
```

Here is upload.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>

<h1>You can upload your files here</h1>

<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" /><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

uploadStatus.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>

<h1>Upload Status</h1>

<div th:if="${message}">
<h2 th:text="${message}"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I use the thymeleaf as the template engine:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am still a beginner and have basic experience with spring boot, I have been looking for the solution for a while so please any help/suggestion to solve the problem will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you include the full stack trace? Does the execution enter the catch block?

Comment: Do this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064000/uploading-file-returns-403-error-spring-mvc ?

Comment: Check this and figure out what can be wrong on your side: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to CSRF (Cross-site request forgery) protection.
Add hidden field with CSRF token on your form.

```
<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Gustlik, your solution helped me a lot and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of the spring boot security (CSRF protection), to solve the problem, there are two possibilities:

1- Adding this line to the upload form, works fine:

```
<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

2- It was also possible to change the security auto-configuration and make my own configuration in order to disable CSRF.
I made use of a @Configuration class as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class configuration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.csrf().disable();
}
}
```

See [Configuring Spring Boot Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration) for a detailed explanation of the spring boot security!

Thanks a lot @Gustlik